# Travelling to Kosovo from The Philippines

Tags: tourist-visas, filipino-citizens, kosovo

I am from The Philippines. How can I apply for a Kosovo tourist visa from the Philippines?

Do I need to travel to a country where there is a Kosovo Embassy such as Turkey?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to apply through the embassy or consulate and the Republic of Kosovo Ministry of Foreign Affairs [web tool directs Filipinos to apply in either Albania or Turkey](http://ambasada-ks.net/us/?page=2,49)

> Visas may be obtained from diplomatic and consular posts of Kosovo in:
>
> Tirana, Albania
>   Ambasada e Republikës së Kosovës në Tiranë
>   Rr. Donika Kastrioti, Vila nr 6, Tiranë
>   E-mail : visa.al@rks-gov.net
>   http://www.ambasada-ks.net/al/
>
> Istanbul, Turkey
>   Konsullata e Përgjithshme e Republikës së Kosovës në Stamboll
>   Vali Konağı Cad. No: 74 D 3
>   Nişantaşı, İstanbul / Turkey
>   E-mail: visa.ist@rks-gov.net
>   http://www.ambasada-ks.net/tr/
>
> Please note that you do not need a visa to visit or transit Kosovo, if:
>
> - You are a holder of a valid biometric residence permit issued by one of the Schengen member states or a valid multi-entry Schengen Visa (max. 15 days stay)
> - You are a holder of a valid Laissez-Passer issued by United Nations Organizations, NATO, OSCE, Council of Europe or European Union
> - You are a holder of a valid travel documents issued by EU Member and Schengen States, United States of America, Canada, Australia and Japan based on the 1951 Convention on Refugee Status or the 1954 Convention on the Status of Stateless Persons, as well as holders of valid travel documents for foreigners (max. 15 days stay)

For convenience, Filipinos are able to obtain e-visas through the Republic of Turkey website.

Worth noting: If you wish to travel to Serbia after visiting Kosovo, you must have initially entered Kosovo through Serbia and have a valid, recent Serbian entry stamp. If you enter Kosovo through Pristina Airport from a country other than Serbia, you cannot enter Serbia afterwards. By land, you must have entered Kosovo though a joint, integrated border post (IBM).

The [Embassy of the Republic of Serbia in Jakarta (Indonesia)](http://www.mfa.gov.rs/en/embassies/serbian-diplomatic-missions/serbian-embassies/87-embassies/87-indonesia) processes visas for applicants from The Philippines.